# git clone, ignoring file

Tags: git, github

I want to clone a GitHub repo that has a giant .exe file in it.  (why?!)  I have zero use for the .exe file, and it is substantially bigger than everything else combined.  Is there a way to ignore the file when I clone it?

My guess is that I would have better luck asking the author to make an exe-less branch!  Hopefully there is some nice way around this though.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326365/git-clone-ignoring-a-directory

Comment: I definitely saw that first, and wasn't satisfied.  So, I asked a slightly more specific question.  One answer states that `git clone` will always clone the whole thing, so I'm asking if there is any way to achieve my goal of not having to download the exe, and yet automate this with a git command.

Comment: I don't think so based on these answers. It looks you have to download it, but you can filter out later.

Comment: Accepted answer below works like a charm

Comment: If you check the comments in the linked answer (or your respository's internals), you will see that the big exe is downloaded, but it is filtered from your working copy. The clone doesn't care about the sparse checkout properties when downloads, this property is important when copying the files from the .git folder to the working copy.

Comment: :(  How would I verify that in the "repository's internals."  Where/how do I look for those .exe files I thought I ignored?  I don't see them in the repo, but would they be cached somewhere?

Comment: The `sparse-checkout` repo is smaller than the one I get from a regular `git clone`.

Comment: It can happen that I am wrong. I didn't test it. It think this command should display what is in your repo: `git ls-tree $(git log -1|head -1|cut -d ' ' -f 2)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2020+: use the more recent [`git sparse-checkout` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout) (that [I introduced here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52916879/6309)):

This will actually clone *without* downloading anything:

```bash
git clone --filter=blob:none --no-checkout https://github.com/git/git
cd git
```

I detail the [exclusion here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59515426/6309):

```bash
# Disablecone mode in .git/config.worktree
git config core.sparseCheckoutCone false

# remove .git\info\sparse-checkout
git sparse-checkout disable

# Add the expected pattern, to include just a subfolder without top files:
git sparse-checkout set !/your.exe

# populate working-tree with only the right files:
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

---

2014: You can try a **[sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13738951/6309)**, which means:

- initializing an empty repo,
- add a remote pointing to the GitHub repo: `git remote add -f origin <url>`,
- `git config core.sparsecheckout true`,
- create a `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file in which you specify what you want to load.

In your case:

```
/*
!yourExe
```

You now can do a:

```
git pull origin master
```

That should download everything *but* your exe.

Comment: This downloads *everything*, including the exe. It just doesn't check it out in the end. It still wastes space in your .git.

Comment: @Atemu You are correct: this 2014 answer is not satisfactory. I have updated it to use the 2020 more recent command `git sparse-checkout`. Let me know if that is working better.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add some minor adaptations to [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)'s answer, here are my steps:

```
# Clone without downloading files
git clone --no-checkout --filter=blob:none https://.../<your_git_repo>.git

# Go inside cloned repo
cd <your_git_repo>

# Disable cone mode in .git/config.worktree
git config core.sparseCheckoutCone false

# Remove .git\info\sparse-checkout
git sparse-checkout disable

# Set retrieval to come: all blobs...
git sparse-checkout set '/*'

# ... except this file
git sparse-checkout add '!/<path_to_file_inside_Git_repo>'

# Now download the list of files just set
git read-tree -mu HEAD
```

If like me you're on a Unix system, be precise about single quotes: this is notably what prevented me to achieve in that answer, on top of the sparse-checkout add/set combination.

Comment: Nice step-by-step process. Upvoted.