# Not download Few Folders of Azure DevOps Repo in Azure DevOps CI Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-pipelines-tasks

I have Created a CI Pipeline in Azure Devops. My Repo is Azure DevOps Repo.

My Repo size is big so i do NOT want some of Folders to be downloaded on agent machine as Those folders are redundant for code build.

What changes i need to do in my pipeline yaml file?

[image]

for example FolderX should not be downloaded

Answer (score 1):

You cannot specific exclude folders during cloning. At present time, Azure DevOps does not support Git blob filters.

Answer (score 1):

It will clone the whole repository content even you add .gitignore.

You could customize the checkout step via Command line task with "[git sparse-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout)".

Sample as below:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: none
- script: |
    git init $(System.TeamProject) && cd $(System.TeamProject)    
    git config core.sparsecheckout true
    echo '/*' >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
    echo '!testfolder2/*' >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
    git remote add origin https://anything:$(PAT)@dev.azure.com/{yourorg}/{yourproject}/_git/{yourrepo}
    git pull origin main
    git checkout main && ls
```

[image]

You can find similar link [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-devops-how-to-checkout-only-the-azure-pipeli/1232270) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23150213/14996050).