# Git clone without specific files

Tags: git, clone

I would like to know how when I make a git clone I could get rid off specific files, let me explain:
For example I do a few commits, in each one I add files ( .m files, .doc file and so on).
Then I must give this project to a client but I've got files in this .git project that doesn't concern him (let's say .m files).
How can I clone to him the Project without any trace of this type of file?
Submodules and subtrees are not the Solutions because the .m files would be everywhere in the Project.

Comment: I don't know git well, but this sounds like you need to make a branch with the files you want, and then clone that. I will look forward to reading a more detailed answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git clone, ignoring a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326365/git-clone-ignoring-a-directory)

Answer (score 4):

Put

***.m**

in your .gitignore file, So that in future when you commit your code, it will be automatically excluded from the commit

Comment: Thank you, but the old .m files that were not ignored first would still be in the git repo right?

Comment: Yes existing files will remain.

Comment: @Theologie 1 thing which you can do, is delete those files from your machine, then commit your code, while doing that you'll your deleted file in the new/updated files list marked as Deleted. Commit and Push the code. Now, you don't have any .m file in your server + once you update your .gitignore file, you'll prevent that happening in future.