# Ignore a particular folder alone during the git clone

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash, git-clone

I am trying to checkout an ios app from Bit-Bucket and trying to clone the repo but it takes too much time since the POD files have been committed there in pod folder. Can I clone the ios repository without the pod folder?

Comment: You can fork the repository create a branch where you remove the POD folder on bitbucket and after this, you can e.g. download this branch as zip.

Comment: Git is implementing "partial clone". With Git 2.19, you can have a try. But it seems not all hosting servers have supported this new feature yet. See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/partial-clone and https://github.blog/2018-09-10-highlights-from-git-2-19/.

Comment: AFAIK you can't do anything while you clone. You have to go back in time and remove these commits. But this will lead to different commit ids, which could lead to problems with other system (like CI/CD). Nevertheless if you need to, you could take a look at [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to remove the files from your local git history and afterwards replace the remote git repo with the clean version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git clone, ignoring a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326365/git-clone-ignoring-a-directory)