# How to ignore some files from repo while cloning from Github?

Tags: git, github, gitignore, ignore

While pushing files to Github, we can ignore files from the Git repo. Can we ignore files while downloading from Github? There are `YAML`, `CONTRIBUTION`, `CODE_OF_CONDUCT`, etc files in Github that we don't want to download from Github while cloning the repo.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your specific question, but check it out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326365/git-clone-ignoring-a-directory

Comment: *While we are pushing files to Github, we can ignore files in git.* No, you can't: what you can push to GitHub are *commits*, not files. The commits have files, or don't have them. That's all there is to it. Note that if you clone a *repository* from GitHub, you get *commits*, not files, again. You can, if you prefer, use GitHub's "download an archive of one specific commit" feature, to get one specific tar or zip archive.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a [partial clone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48852630/6309), which is stricter than a sparse checkout:

- a sparse checkout means: you clone everything but restore only some files in the working tree.
- a partial clone means: you clone only what you need (then restore everything cloned in the working tree)

The partial clone uses a [`git rev-list --filter` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---filterltfilter-specgt).